# Unable to install pymssql

Tags: python, macos

I was trying to install pymssql .For this I use pip and installed it using a virtual environment according to instructions mentioned [here](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html#using-the-installer) But when I say

(my_new_env)tmp> pip install pymssql

I see the following errors :

> Downloading pymssql-2.0.0b1-dev-20111019.tar.gz (5.0Mb): 5.0Mb
>   downloaded  Running setup.py egg_info for package pymssql
>    Traceback
>   (most recent call last):
>        File "", line 14, in 
>        File "/private/tmp/my_new_env/build/pymssql/setup.py", line 41, in 
>          from Cython.Distutils import build_ext as _build_ext    ImportError: No module named Cython.Distutils    Complete output from
>   command python setup.py egg_info:    Traceback (most recent call
>   last):
>
> File "", line 14, in
>
> File "/private/tmp/my_new_env/build/pymssql/setup.py", line 41, in
>
> from Cython.Distutils import build_ext as _build_ext
>
> **ImportError: No module named Cython.Distutils**

I googled a bit for this issue.Do I have to install Cython or something? If so some instructions in this direction would be helpful.
Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to install Cython.  It is available on PyPi so you may be able to do:

```
pip install cython
```

That may not work on windows (I really don't know), but if it doesn't check out this page:
http://cython.org/#download

On that page you will see a link to windows installers.  Pick the right one and you should be good to go.

Comment: Pip would usually do this for you automatically.  But Pymsql has issues with cython deps.  http://code.google.com/p/pymssql/issues/detail?id=90